# c # retrieve the max Size from database of each value using DataReader

Tags: c#, .net, database

i am trying to get the max Size of a value in the database for example i have a table facture 
and an attribute of this table Nom varchar(40) for the type of the value i used GetFieldType 
but i don't know how to retrieve the 40 ( max Size in the database )  i need this to do some verification on the type and size : if the type is varchar and the legth of the value is < 40 then i have to add spaces if the type is numeric then i have to add 000 
example  i have a value DATA its legth is < 40 the i add 36 spaces to this value if it's a numeric i add 36 zeros  to the value 
here is the code to show how to retrive the type of each value i need the method to retrieve alse the Size of each value without using GetSchemaTable

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
             {

                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows) { }
                     // if (cursor["mat_fisc"]
                     mat_fisc = reader[0].ToString();
                     string type = reader.GetFieldType(0).ToString();}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

You can retrieve the size of the column using `ColumnSize`

Comment: i already used the GetSchemaTable , but it won't give me the size of each value in the loop while it only gives the ColumnSize of each column

Comment: Value ? You mean you want the size of the cell? Because you said that you wanted to retrieve the max size of the column.

Try this:

            SqlDataReader sdr = new SqlDataReader();
            foreach (DataRow dr in sdr.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
            {
                string b = dr["ColumnName"].ToString();
                int a = (int)dr["ColumnSize"];
            }